# How can I wait to send an express response until after async loop is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, axios

Wanting to do something like below. I assume that it's an issue with the async call as the response that I send is always an empty array, but the API is returning data. Pretty new to this, any input is greatly appreciated!

```
app.get('/:id/starships', (req, res) => {
  let person = findPersonById(people, req.params.id)[0];
  let starshipUrls = person.starships;
  for(let i=0; i<starshipUrls.length; i++){
    axios.get(starshipUrls[i]).then(response => {
      starships.push(response.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
  res.json(starships);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`axios.get` returns a [*promise*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for multiple promises:

```
app.get('/:id/starships', (req, res) => {
  let person = findPersonById(people, req.params.id)[0];
  Promise.all(person.starships.map(url => axios.get(url)))
    .then(responses => res.json(responses.map(r => r.data)))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

Comment: Ahh I had never seen Promise.all before. Works perfectly, thanks so much!